# Unable to Determine Parse Mode

Tags: html

I am trying to validate the following site: http://www.canning.co.nz/Game/index.html

I am getting the following warning: Unable to Determine Parse Mode!

Can someone please describe what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: What are you parsing it with?

Comment: What is parsing... Do you mean the editor that I am using?

Comment: I mean what are you using that gives you that error?

Comment: I presume that I just need to add a line to my html code. Is this correct? The funny thing is, I did not have any errors of this nature with another page, and that page had no lines of code with anything about a Parse Mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the warning “Unable to Determine Parse Mode!” from the W3C Markup Validator, then the warning is immediately followed by an explanation. It is fairly technical, but it boils down to saying that the validator will treat the document as “classic,” nominally SGML-based HTML, since its decision mechanisms do not tell it unambiguously whether it should do that or use XHTML.

The warning is triggered e.g. if you make a typo in the doctype declaration, say write Transtional and not Transitional. The reason is that the typo makes the declaration unrecognized.

Perhaps you fixed your document after posting the question, since now it validates without a warning:
http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.canning.co.nz%2FGame%2Findex.html